# How to get name of the month in MS EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say in column A1, I have the below value in the format dd/mm/yy.

**13/04/18**

I need to print the name of the month which i **APRIL** in column A2.

How can we achieve that?

I've tried the below:

1. `=TEXT(date,"mmmm")` will work only if the format is mm/dd/yy.
2. I've tried to change the date format to mm/dd/yy and then to the month name which works but I don't need one unwanted column

   IN B1 column   `=DATE(RIGHT(A1,2)+2000,MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))`

   IN C1 column   `=TEXT(date,"mmmm")`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting the data type of your input cell (say, A1) to date (you know, right-click -> format cell -> number -> date)? If the source of your data is of type `date`, your formula `=TEXT(A1,"mmm") should yield the correct result (i.e. month name). Just tested it and it works.

Comment: @FDavidov the issue is that the OP's local settings are `mm/dd/yyyy` and when they get "dates" in `dd/mm/yy` format excel treats them as strings and not true dates, so the dates need to be parsed manually into true dates.  Then one can apply `TEXT()` to that.

Comment: @ScottCraner, Excel interprets dates according to the locale of the computer in which it is running. So, there are three options (assuming that the input format is going to be always the same): (1) extract the month part of the input and then use `TEXT(DATE(2018,MID(A1,4,2),1),"mmm")`, (2) convert into B2 the string to a legal date format and then `TEXT(B2,"mmm")` or (3) change the locale of the computer to match the input date format.

Comment: @FDavidov and that is what my formula is doing.  It parses the date when it does not match the local settings.

Comment: @ScottCraner, you are right, except that the year and day are not important at all so you can just put `2018` for the year and `1` for the day.

Answer (score 1):

so combine the two:

```
=TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(A1,2)+2000,MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2)),"mmmm")
```